# openCL-openGL interop stopped working after X upgrade

Tags: opengl, opencl, xorg

The following code used to work:

```
cl_context_properties Properties [] = {
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentContext(),
    CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentDisplay(), 
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties) CL.Platform, 
    0
};

CL.Context = clCreateContext(Properties, 1, CL.Device, 0, 0, &err);
if (err < 0) printf("Context error %i!\n", err);
```

but now prints

```
Context error -1000!
```

If I comment out

```
    //CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentContext(),
    //CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentDisplay(),
```

then it works fine. So, it would seem the issue is with the glX calls.

Now, what has changed is that I have upgraded X on my machine. I run AMD catalyst, and this upgrade resulted in the loss of my display, so after purging and reinstalling fglrx, I regained my display but suspect something got broken in the process. As as aside, I used to play Zandronum on this machine but since the upgrade, any attempt to play yields the following error:

```
zandronum: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0.
```

I don't think this is a coincidence.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed in debugging. I can print the results of the glX calls in gdb:

```
(gdb) p Properties
$1 = {8200, 8519632, 8202, 6308672, 4228, 140737247522016, 0}
```

but I don't know how to verify any of it, or get further information on the values these calls are returning. What steps can I take to get to the root of the problem? Am I even looking in the right place?